# URL redirection in client side

Tags: redirect, next.js

I have a list of **current_urls** that need to be redirected to **new_urls** list. Using mapping in the server.js file, the URLs are being redirected only when the url is hit on the server, but if I navigate from the client side, I get 404 because that url doesn't go the server.

So, how can I handle the client-side navigation redirects?
P.S. Using NextJs only.